# Is carbohydrate an important part of phospholipid?

Tags: cell

My professor tells us that carbohydrate is an important part of phospholipid, but phospholipid is composed of Choline, Phosphate, Glycerol and two Fattyacid, and I don't think even one of them is carbohydrate.

What's wrong with my statements?

Comment: Question: What is a fatty acid and which elements do you find in it?

Comment: Similar question: what are the elements in glycerol?

Comment: @Chris Sir, fatty acid is a kind of lipids and I find C,H,O in it.

Comment: There you have the carbohydrate part you are looking for.

Comment: @Chris fatty acid is also carbohydrates? I don't think so. It's not in the textbook. Lipids and carbohydrates are completely different.

Comment: No, but the fatty acids have a carbohydrate tail.

Comment: @Chris do you mean hydrocarbon tail? And phosphoinositol would have something similar to a carbohydrate as its head group.

Comment: Phospholipids have lipids, of course, but those are bound to glycerol, a 3 carbon carbohydrate that is usually derived from glucose.  Glycerol is the only carbohydrate (or even carbohydrate-like) part of the phospholipid.

Comment: @JasonPatterson Thanks, that's the right answer I am looking for! Would you mind write this as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your thinking is correct based on typical carbohydrates, but glycerol, the backbone of the phospholipid, is a 3-carbon carbohydrate that is usually derived from glucose.  It is not a sugar, but it does fall into the general class of polyols (aka sugar alcohols) that are a type of carbohydrate.

A carbohydrate definitely is an important structural part of the phospholipid, but your instructor probably should have been more clear in describing why that is the case; I can definitely understand your confusion here.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong in your statements! 
Maybe your professor was talking about *glycolipids*, that are lipids (also *phospholipids*) with a carbohydrate attached; they can be found on the outer surface of all eukaryotic cell membranes. They are important because they work as a recognition site for specific chemicals or for antibodies.